# Add catalog to remote ssis

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssms, ssms-2014

First of all I am new to ssis so sorry if this question is simple to answer.

I open sql management studio 2014, and connect to my sqlserver. 
Secondly I connect to my integration services.

Now I have an .ispac file that needs a catalog in my integration services. However I do not have a catalog in my integration services all I have is the following:

[image]
How do I add a catalog and deploy my .ispac file to this catalog?

Clarification:

I have 2 servers: 1 crm server and 1 sql server. I have no direct access to the sql server, to connect to the database I use sql management studio 2012.

On the crm server the integration services are installed. I add these to the sql management studio using the connect button (see picture)

I have a deployment file (.ispac) but in order to deploy this I need a catalog. However on the Integration Services that have been added in the sql studio it is not possible to add a catalog. It only has MSDB and I need SSISDB.

How can I deploy my deployment file?

Answer (score 0):

The catalog is part of the Database Engine, not Integration Services.

[Create the SSIS Catalog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471509(v=sql.120).aspx)

If you already have a catalog then you just need to connect to the Database Engine. You should find it under a folder named Integration  Services Catalogs.

Comment: Yes, I know that but I can not add a catalog on my sql server. I get the error that it cannot find the 'SSISDBBackup.bak'. This is because my sql server does not have the integration services installed. These are installed on a seperate server that has no database engine.

I will try to explain my setup:
 - Crm server, on this server the integration services are installed.
 - SQL server
 - Sql server management studio is installed on the crm server and is connected to an instance on my sql server.
 - I have an .ispac file that I need to deploy to my integeration services.

And here I am stuck